# Windows Phone 7 Sliding Menu

Tags: windows-phone-7, slidingmenu

I am developing a app in windows phone 7. In that app i have completed more than 30 screens. Now i want to add sliding menu in all the pages.

Please let me any idea to add sliding menu in all the pages.

I have try WindowsPhoneControl. I create a menu with listbox and i try to add all the pages.

User Control Page:-

```
<UserControl x:Class="NewExample.SlidingMenu"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="400">
      <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="#FFB4B4B4">
            <Button Command="{Binding testButton1}" Content="Test Button 1" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,10,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="376" />
            <Button Command="{Binding testButton2}" Content="Test Button 2" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,72,0,0" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="376" />
            <Button Command="{Binding testButton3}" Content="Test Button 3" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,132,0,0" Name="button3" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="376" />
            <Button Command="{Binding testButton4}" Content="Test Button 4" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,196,0,0" Name="button4" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="376" />
        </Grid>
    </UserControl>
```

Page:-

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--ContentPanel -  place additional content here-->
        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="{Binding gridMargin}">

            <Button Command="{Binding slideButton}" Content="Slide" Height="70" Name="slideButton" Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
            <ScrollViewer Margin="0,80,0,100">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="Index Page 3" FontSize="28" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                    <Button Width="476" Command="{Binding getPageStackButton}" Content="Get Pages From PageStack" Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0" Name="button12" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                    <Button Command="{Binding messageBoxExampleButton}" Content="Message Box Example" Height="72" Name="button1" Width="476" />
                    <Button Command="{Binding orderDetailButton}" Content="Order Detail" Height="72" Name="button3" Width="476" />
                    <Button Command="{Binding customMessageButton}" Content="Custom Message Box" Height="72" Name="button2" Width="476" />

                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <local:BottomTabBar Margin="0,660,0,0"/>                
            <Grid x:Name="SettingsPane" Width="400"
             Margin="{Binding slideMargin}"
             Grid.Row="0">
                <local:SlidingMenu Width="400" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
            </Grid> 
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

i just change the margin of the slideMenu and the page when i click the slider button in the page.

But it is not working like sliding menu. Please let me any other idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best method, but is very easy.

If you want the menu to slide in from the bottom, change the XAML to something similar:

```
<NewExample:SlidingMenu x:Name="ucMain"Height="500" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,0,-500"/>
```

Add reference to System.Windows.Threading.

Add a Loaded event to the Page:

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SlideIn();
}
```

The rest of the code:

```
private void SlideIn()
    {
        DispatcherTimer timerMenuIn = new DispatcherTimer();
        timerMenuIn.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        timerMenuIn.Tick += timerMenuIn_Tick;
        timerMenuIn.Start();
    }

    void timerMenuIn_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int speed = 7;
        if (ucMain.Margin.Bottom >= -speed)
        {
            ucMain.Margin = new Thickness(
            ucMain.Margin.Left,
            ucMain.Margin.Top,
            ucMain.Margin.Right, 0);
            ((DispatcherTimer)sender).Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            ucMain.Margin = new Thickness(
            ucMain.Margin.Left,
            ucMain.Margin.Top,
            ucMain.Margin.Right,
            ucMain.Margin.Bottom + speed);
        }
    }
```

You could easily change the direction, by changing the other margin values. Hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can download the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/). And follow the instructions [here](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-7-navigation-transitions-step-by-step-guide) under the "Using Page Transitions via Code" section, the bit you want to read is halfway down the webpage.